# Trying to link my C++ executable with Fortran library (Cygwin environment)

Tags: c++, cygwin, fortran

All my fortran sources compiled fine with

```
gfortran -g -c fortran_source.f
```

and archived in a single library called "mylibrary.a"
In there, there exists a function of interest called "myfunction"

In my C++ file, I have:

```
extern "C" void myfunction_(/* all pointers */);
int main(){
cerr << "Mark 1" << endl;
myfunction_(/* all pointers or address_of my variables */);
cerr << "Mark 2" << endl;
}
```

I compile my c++ executable, linking the library with

```
g++ mainfile.cpp -L./ -lmylibrary -lgfortran
```

No errors or warnings...

However, when I run my program it hangs at the first point where myfunction is called (prints "Mark1" but not "Mark 2")...

Note that this program builds and runs correctly on a Linux machine with ifort (linking -lifcore).

Thank you very much!

Comment: `g++ mainfile.cpp -L./mylibrary`  ?  you meant `g++ mainfile.cpp mylibrary.a`?

Comment: Btw, Tim thank you for making the question appear nice!

Comment: I'm pretty sure g77 and gfortran handle name mangling differently - by default, g77 mangles a function named "foo" to something you could call with "foo_" in C. Not sure how gfortran handles name mangling.

Comment: @Chris `-L./mylibrary` is to specify directory, not library.  you are not linking to your library at all.

Comment: @George g77 appends `__` to fortran function/subs, gfortran/ifort appends `_` by default

Comment: @Chris significant changes to the question should probably be posted as a separate question.. so that all responses don't need to be updated to keep in sync with the question. With this change in question you'd be best to include a minimal example fortran function exhibiting the behaviour you mention, so that we have a complete program to work off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to name your library libMyLibrary.a and put it in your current directory then you can link it using

```
g++ mainfile.cpp -L. -lMyLibrary
```

or

```
g++ mainfile.cpp ./libMyLibrary.a
```

You can put the library somewhere else. In the first case you'd change the `-L.` to `-L/path/to/the/lib`, in the second `./libMyLibrary.a` to `/path/to/the/lib/libMyLibrary.a`

Comment: Michael Anderson -- You are right! (so is aaa). That was an obvious mistake.... It now links correctly (one also needs to use -lgfortran)...